# How to share Visual Studio 2022 Code Cleanup settings with team

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, code-cleanup, editorconfig

Hi I am using Visual Studio 2022. I want to share code cleanup on save setting with my team. How can i do it? I tried to export settings and import it but without success.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible at the moment, 2023-09-19, but there is a ticket for it at Developer Community:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Provide-a-way-to-share-Code-Cleanup-prof/824754

You can however achieve quite a good result with these settings:

Since Visual Studio 17.3 you can set these values in Configure Code Cleanup:

```
Fix analyzer warnings and errors set in EditorConfig
Fix all warnings and errors set in EditorConfig
```

[image]

Then make sure to set Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Code Cleanup -> "Run Code Cleanup profile on Save"

[image]

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/bringing-code-cleanup-on-save-to-visual-studio-2022-17-1-preview-2/

If every team member has these settings then it comes pretty close to shared Code Cleanup settings.

Comment: If you vote down please add a comment why. Hard to improve answers otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Menu: `Tools -> Options`
Open tree to: `Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> General`

Use the `Generate .editorconfig file from Settings` button.

[image]
Check that in to the root of your code repo.